# Can the iterator be shared between vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

In c++, if I have two arrays `a[10] and b[10]`, I can introduce an index i can be used for both arrays points to the (i+1)-th element, `a[i] and b[i]`. Is the iterator can be shared as well or I need to do something like:

```
vector<int> a;
vector<int> b;    //assume both are initiated and same
vector<int>::iterator i;    //assume program know i=10 and *i=20 in vector a 
vector<int>::iterator j = b.begin();

for(;j != b.end();j++){
    if(*j == *i){
        break;
    }
}
```

and then I get the iterator j which points to the same position but in vector b? Can I simply know the position of i in a and then `j=b.begin()+pos(i)`

Comment: What does it mean for an iterator to be "equal to ten"?

Comment: It is unclear what the intent is. While as stated the clear answer is NO, the answer to your real question might be YES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterators in the Standard C++ Library are modeled after pointers, not after indexes. In the same way that pointers cannot be shared among multiple arrays, iterators cannot be shared among vectors or other collections.

If you need to iterate multiple vectors in parallel, you can use indexes rather than iterators. If you need to find the position of an iterator, you can use `std::distance` like this:

```
std::distance(b.begin(), my_iter)
```

If you need to move an iterator `i` in vector `a` to the same position as iterator `j` in vector `b`, you can do this:

```
auto i = a.begin();
// j is an iterator in vector "b"
advance(i, distance(b.begin(), j));
```

Comment: Note that there are libraries that support `zip`ing containers and parallel iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
#include <iterator>
j = b.begin() + distance(i, a.begin());
```

Comment: What more, the above is going to be pretty efficient.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Iterators cannot be shared between two containers. If you want to have a common index for iterating over the two `vector`s, use `operator[]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Can iterator be shared between vectors?

No, each iterator variable can refer to an element of at most one container, and it is not legal to compare iterators referring to elements in different containers.

But... in the code `if(*j == *i)` you are not comparing the iterators, but rather the values that the iterators refer to. This is perfectly legal, regardless of the containers that the iterators `i` and `j` refer to (as long as they are *dereference-able*, i.e. they refer to a valid element).

> and then I get the iterator j which points to the same position but in vector b?

This does not make sense in the context of the code above. If what you mean to do is selecting an element in one container and the iterator in the second container that refers to the same position (index), then you can do that:

```
j = std::next(b.begin(),std::distance(a.begin(),i));
```

Then again, there are algorithms that could be used for the same purpose:

```
std::find()          // find an element equal to the last argument
std::find_if()       // find an element that matches a functor
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not compare iterators for different collections, not even of the same type and with equal data. Just because the two vectors appear to be the same, they are two different objects, and the memory occupied by the underlying data is therefore different.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of doing this would be by using std::find() as follows:

`j = std::find(b.begin(), b.end(), *i);`